# initializing an SQL statement using ./init/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Here's my docker-compose.yaml file. whenever i run `docker-compose up`, it returns `Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification:` Heres the docker-compose.yaml file-

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - user_service


  user_service:
    build:
      context: ./user_service
    restart: always
    container_name: user_service_container
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - user_db
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://postgres:1234@user_db:5432/User

  user_db:
    image: postgres:16.0
    container_name: user_db_container
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 1234
      POSTGRES_DB: User
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./init/user_service_init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/user_service_init.sql
      - user_db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
    user_db_data:
```

this is my folder structure currently-
[image]

here's my sql file which is inside init folder(init/user_service_init.sql):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    password_hashed VARCHAR
);
```

and below is the full error that im getting:
[image: error image]

I tried googling and also tried looking in stackoverflow but did not find any specific solution.

Comment: Always try and post error messages and similar evidence as text. As far as I can see in the picture you have a typo. It says "initt/user_service_init.sql" with two "tt"s.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include especially the error message in plain text?  Is it possible some part of the directory hierarchy has a colon in a directory name, which Docker is then interpreting as separating the host and container paths?

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it my removing the white spaces from the folder names. apparently bash scripts malfunction when there is white spaces or any weird character in the folder names.